# UnicodeDecodeError in Django (oscar and fabric)

Tags: django, fedora, fabric, django-oscar

I am currently trying to use django-oscar package as a solution to practical ecommerce with Django.

I started by it's docs but when trying to run the sandbox locally as indicated [here](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/sandbox.html), but when running

```
$ make sandbox
```

I get (after a long downloading series) this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/valle/.virtualenvs/oscar/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
   File "/home/valle/.virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/valle/.virtualenvs/oscar/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 79: ordinal not in range(128)
make: ** [install] Erro 1
```

I also got the same error early this morning when installing fabric. I use Fedora 20 in VirtualBox.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Python 2 or 3?  It may be something related to your Python version since Py2 and Py3 think of Unicode strings differently.

Comment: I am currently using python 2.7.5